# Are static segments of routePath in TYPO3 RouteEnhancer optional or mandatory?

Tags: routes, typo3, url-routing, typo3-9.x

Since TYPO3 Version 9.5 RouteEnhancers can be used to translate parameters of extensions to nice and human-readable URL-paths. Those usually contain a ["static keyword (previously known to some as "postVarSets" keyword for some TYPO3 folks)](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/9.5/Feature-86365-RoutingEnhancersAndAspects.html)" and a dynamic part based on f.e. path_segment field of the extension-record, like this:

```
routeEnhancers:
  MyExtDetail:
    type: Plugin
    namespace: tx_myext_pi1
    routePath: '/myext-detail/{uid}'
    aspects:
      uid:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: tx_myext_item
        routeFieldName: path_segment
```

**My Question is:**
Is a unique static part like "/myext-detail" here absolutely mandatory (as I believe it was with RealUrl) or is it entirely optional, or on what does this depend? Can I simply leave it out, or will I run into trouble, at least under certain conditions, or are there advantages I would miss?

I tried leaving it out in a simple case, and it did seem to work, but I'm unsure about more complex scenarios.

Comment: It is not required, but you can get in trouble when different plugins on the same site are listening to the same segment. So, it is a good approach to "prefix" the UID/path_segment with a static part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may come in trouble.

But it is not necessary if you have a clean configuration.

Assuming you have two different plugins which show records in a list with pagination and as single (detail):
if these plugins reside on different pages you could configure single/detail display with just the record number (depending on the page you select the record from another table.)
even the page of the pagination could be configured without additional path segment: just add a prefix like `page-` to the page number.
and although the paginations are based on different URL parameters (like `tx_plugin1[page]` and `tx_plugin2[page]`) the resulting URL may look the same as the configuration would be page dependent.

example:

```yaml
  Record1Plugin:
    type: Extbase
    limitToPages:
      - 123
    extension: MyExt
    plugin: Record1Plugin
    routes:
      -
        routePath: '/page-{page}'
        _controller: 'Record1::list'
        _arguments:
          page: showPage
      -
        routePath: '/{record1Id}'
        _controller: 'Record1::show'
        _arguments:
          record1id: record1
    defaultController: 'Record1::list'
    defaults:
      page: '0'
    requirements:
      page: \d+

  Record2Plugin:
    type: Extbase
    limitToPages:
      - 456
    extension: MyExt
    plugin: Record2Plugin
    routes:
      -
        routePath: '/page-{page}'
        _controller: 'Record1::list'
        _arguments:
          page: showPage
      -
        routePath: '/{record2Id}'
        _controller: 'Record2::show'
        _arguments:
          record2Id: record2
    defaultController: 'Record2::list'
    defaults:
      page: '0'
    requirements:
      page: \d+
```

Comment: So leaving out the static part in the detail-paths this will be unproblematic as long as it is clear (via limitToPages), that on each detail-page only one detail-path-Configuration is allowed?

Comment: should be. I have not detect any problems yet.